# UIDatePicker - only select times that are 15mins from now

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Im trying to implement a `UIDatePicker` that only allows the user to select dates that are 15mins from the current time or more. The minute component is in intervals of 15mins. The user cannot select a time that has already passed. This is what I have tried, and I believe I am very close, but I am unsure of what I am missing to perfect it;

```
        UIDatePicker * datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 163)];
        datePicker.clipsToBounds=YES;
        datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeTime;
        datePicker.minuteInterval = 15;
        datePicker.minimumDate=[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*15];
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"EE dd MMM"];
        NSString *weekday = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        self.time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Time: %@",weekday,[dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];//self.time is an NSString
```

And this is my dateChanged method:

```
- (void)dateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"EE dd MMM"];
NSString *weekday = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: sender.date];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

self.time =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Time: %@",weekday,[dateFormatter stringFromDate:sender.date]];
```

}

However if its 15:56 and I select 16:00, I get 16:12. Which is incorrect. I should not be able to select 16:00, I should only be able to select 16:15. Another example, is if its 16:10, i should only be able to select 16:30.etc. Im having a bit of difficult with this. It rounds it to the nearest quarter of an hour. Any questions please let me know.

The user can only select in 15mins intervals, and must be 15mins from the current 15min interval. For example, if its 10:50, the user should only be able to select 11:15. If is 10:20, the user should only be able to select 10:45.

I believe I am very close but I cannot figure out the rest of the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try algo: targetMinTime = currentTime + 30 - (currentTime % 15)

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code:

```
currentTime = [NSDate date]; 
pickedTime = [value from picker]

if pickedTime - currentTime < 15 minutes {
 pickedTime +=15
}
```